# How to keep an Aspect-fixed UIView filling up the screen in any screen orientation programmatically in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

I want just this simple effect:

that I have a picture automatically orients itself according to the device/screen orientation, it alway fill up the whole screen without stretching itself so that the aspect doesn't change.

I work with Xcode though I got a lot of answer with storyboard and UI builder,I really don't like such ways that work well but you have no idea how it works, so I was trying to find the way to do it programmatically instead.

I've tried to set a image view as subview, but it doesn't fix well after the device is rotated, it either stretch to fill the screen or move to somewhere else with size unchanged (when I trie to recalculate the frame and apply to the subview), then I tried to override the drawrect func, of the UIView, the frame works fine but the animation of rotating is broken (it stretches it self during the rotation and then skip into the final frame).

the perfect effect I want is just like iOS original photo app, when I check a photo, it resizes to fix the screen, and even when I rotate the screen, the animation works just perfect, the rotating and scaling happens in the same time and no skip of stretch happens. could anyone please give me some help?

THANKS!!!!!

the way I set the frame:

```
func locating (imgsize:CGSize,scrsize:CGSize) ->CGRect {
var size:CGSize
var ori:CGPoint
if ((imgsize.height / imgsize.width) * scrsize.width>=scrsize.height){
    size = CGSize(width:scrsize.width,height:imgsize.height*(scrsize.width/imgsize.width))
    ori = CGPoint(x:0,y:scrsize.height-imgsize.height*(scrsize.width/imgsize.width))

}
else {
    size = CGSize(width:imgsize.width*(scrsize.height/imgsize.height),height:scrsize.height)
    ori = CGPoint(x:-(imgsize.width*(scrsize.height/imgsize.height)-scrsize.width)/2,y:0)
    }
return CGRect(origin:ori,size:size)
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from math's stuff! here is also the solutions that can work for you!

- Set image width and height to superview width and height.

`self.imageView.frame = self.imageView.superView?.bounds`

- Then set your `imageView's` `contentMode` property to `aspectFill` or `aspectFit`

  1. `self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;`
  2. `self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;`

Comment: thanks！this helps too much！ it works almost perfectly，only one thing is that in scaleaspectfill/fit，I can only set the image in the center, is there any way to align it to one side at the same time it is scaled to fill/fit the superview? (Just like I have a very high image, it scales to meet the width of screen, but the height exceeded too much, I want then to align it to the bottom because the content of the image I want to show is exactly there, is there any way? Do I have to calculate the frame and use the redraw mode?

Comment: might be this third party library will do the things you wish : https://github.com/reydanro/UIImageViewAligned

Comment: Thanks for so much help!